# Set thread thread priority on a WCF application by operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, wcf, iis

Is there any "clean" way to set the priority of the thread that executes a request on a synchronous call to a WCF service? I know the sentence

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority
```

But perhaps it's a better solution.

Context:

We've got our business layer on a WCF application, it attends two kind of calls, one the one hand from an ASPNET MVC application (web front on the same server), and on the other hand from various console applications which execute some batch process not interactive on multiple threads raising the CPU usage at top and decreasing the performance of the front requests (users on their browsers).

We know that we can change the arquitechture to separate the server on two or more servers, and on some customers we've done something similar (separating front and back, multiple servers, balancers), but in tiny customers, the batch processes only executes on very few moments and it isn't reasonable (by budget) to set another machine or another iis application (shared server) for that peaks. It's important that the batch processes executes on better performance (using 100% CPU as they can), but always the web front must be priority.

-- UPDATE 22/02/2018 --

I know that post [Changing thread priority on WCF RIA Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983136/changing-thread-priority-on-wcf-ria-service) is a solution, I'll point it at start of the question, but I want to know if someone could guide me to a better solution, I've developed that one already.

Comment: Why not set a lower priority when you start your multiple threads for the batch processes? It is going to require not using the thread pool anymore, but I doubt it will be too much of a issue.

Comment: Yeah, the processes are started with BelowNormal priorit, but the problem are not the console applications, but the iis worker process of the wcf services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing thread priority on WCF RIA Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983136/changing-thread-priority-on-wcf-ria-service)